# how to stop Pending Alarm of all Applications from another application

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am developing a security app. When my app starts, I wrote a service that kill all other running processes. It works fine. But now i want to Stop all the Pending Intents from Alarm Manager because it can be security risk.I am thinking like, an attacker can use this alarm activity like a time bomb..Is there any possibility to dismiss all pending Intent of other applications ?